# BluetoothGattCallback - onConnectionStateChange returns status22

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I am developing an Android application to interface with Bluetooth module dual mode.

Due to the module is dual mode, I am confronting the same problems described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23061558/2031219).

However I trying to do a workaround, because after first connection the callback onConnectionStateChange() returns status 133. Always in the onStop() method from Main Activity, I close BluetoothGatt object to free resources. Further was added bluetoothGatt.disconnect() before bluetooth.close().

When was called disconnect(), my cellphone get more connections with the module, however after reconnecting sometimes, the callback onConnectionStateChange returns status 22.

I didn't find about status 22 in the [BluetoothGatt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html) documentation.

**UPDATE**
In [BLE callbacks are passed status codes that are not in the public API.](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=851#c4) topic is about status 22 and others.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`133` error code: Connect timeout or device not found.

<s>`22` error code: The bluetooth is closed then device is disconnected.</s>

`22` error code: The Connection Terminated By Local Host error code indicates that the local device terminated the connection.

Comment: 22 is defined by the Bluetooth standard. It means "The Connection Terminated By Local Host error code indicates that the local device terminated the connection."

Comment: it would be really great to have a link to documentation here.  i'd like to handle all these status codes.